# Why does WCF service create its own type?

Tags: .net, wcf

In my WCF project, I have a type that comes from a different library:

```
LibraryB.SomeClass
```

In the svc.cs file for the service, I use the above type in a parameter:

```
GetEmployees(LibraryB.SomeClass someClass)
```

In the web app that is hosting the service, a type is created for the service:

```
MyWebApp.ServiceAReference.ServiceAClient serviceClient = new MyWebApp.ServiceAReference.ServiceAClient();
```

But when I reference the method:

```
serviceClient.GetEmployees(someClass);
```

The intellisense for the parameter is of type:

```
MyWebApp.ServiceA.SomeClass
```

In the web app, someClass is of type LibraryB.SomeClass and not MyWebApp.ServiceA.SomeClass.

Is there some way to tell the web service to send the type LibraryB.SomeClass across the wire?  Or is there something different I should be doing?

Comment: By default, the WCF service itself and the client share **nothing** but the contract (e.g. the interface defining the service methods and their data types involved). The client is **totally independent** of the server. Based on the data contracts, the client will re-create the types that are being serialized across the wire, to be able to use them on the client side - but those are **separate, distinct** types in the client's scope, that just serialize to the same XML message format on the wire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client does not always have access to the server's types. The server might not even be your code! For that reason proxy objects are created on the client side to represent the server's objects.

If the server and client side share the asemblies that contain the type that is sent over the wire, you can tell your application to re-use it when you add your service reference.

[image: Add Service Reference]

Comment: When I do that, it then doesn't recognize ServiceAClient (I've updated the post for this).

Comment: Did you add a reference to the DLL that contains the type in your client project?

Comment: Yes.  Both the service and web app have a reference to LibraryB.